# calculate mean (or uniquely mark) groups that match critearia

Tags: r, performance, data.table, range

This goes back to a question I've asked some time ago - I'm still struggling in the same area.

I have a data.table with some values ('value'), lower limits ('min_val') and upper limits ('max_val'):

```
   | value | min_val | max_val |
1: | 94.001 | 94.00 | 94.02 |
2: | 94.002 | 94.00 | 94.03 |
3: | 94.003 | 94.01 | 94.04 |
4: | 95 | 94.98 | 95.02 |
5: | 100.00 | 99.00 | 101.00 |
6: | 100.10 | 99.10 | 101.00 |
7: | 200.00 | 199.00 | 201.00 |
8: | 200.10 | 199.00 | 201.00 |
```

With your help I have the count:

```
   | value | min_val | max_val | count | id |
1: | 94.001 | 94.00 | 94.02 |  1       |  1 |
2: | 94.002 | 94.00 | 94.03 |  2       |  2 |
3: | 94.003 | 94.01 | 94.04 |  2       |  2 |
4: | 95     | 94.98 | 95.02 |  1       |  3 |
5: | 100.00 | 99.00 | 101.00 | 2       |  4 |
6: | 100.10 | 99.10 | 101.00 | 2       |  4 |
7: | 200.00 | 199.00 | 201.00 | 2      |  5 |
8: | 200.10 | 199.00 | 201.00 | 2      |  5 |
```

Now I want to uniquely identify (col id) each "count group" so that I can use the identified later on (by=id).
I've tried calculating the mean of 'value' column hoping I'll get unique identifiers but the mean function returns 1/count. Not sure how to proceed - I'm stuck as I don't understand how to "go backwards" while doing the computations (example: for 94.003, I need to compare the next element of column value to it and also the previous element):

```
dat[, count := mapply(function(mi,ma) mean(mi < value & value < ma), min_val, max_val)]
```

input:

```
    library(data.table)
dat <- setDT(structure(list(value = c(94.01, 94.02, 94.03, 95, 100, 100.1, 200, 200.1), min_val = c(94, 94, 94.01, 94.98, 99, 99.1, 199, 199), max_val = c(94.02, 94.03, 94.04, 95.02, 101, 101, 201, 201)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L)))
dat[, count := mapply(function(mi,ma) sum(mi < value & value < ma), min_val, max_val)]
```

I'm struggling with this for a few days. The only thing I could think of is that I need to modify the method that does the count so that I do the marking the same way. I did not find a solution. I use this method to generate the count

```
dat[, count := mapply(function(mi,ma) sum(mi < value & value < ma), min_val, max_val)]
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Column id in the 2nd table. I'm not set on having the group numbered, could be anything really as long as it's unique to the group (like mean or the value rows from the grp)

Comment: I think there's a problem with the count column as described. E.g. values 94.001, 94.002 and 94.003 all fall betwen the min_val and max_val of the first row, which should indicate a count of 3, and no values in the first column fall between 94.01 and 94.04, which should mean a count of 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data.table::rleid`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, id:=rleid(count)]
```

Output:

```
    value min_val max_val count    id
    <num>   <num>   <num> <int> <int>
1: 94.001   94.00   94.02     1     1
2: 94.002   94.00   94.03     2     2
3: 94.003   94.01   94.04     2     2
4: 95.000   94.98   95.02     1     3
```

Input:

```
structure(list(value = c(94.001, 94.002, 94.003, 95), min_val = c(94, 
94, 94.01, 94.98), max_val = c(94.02, 94.03, 94.04, 95.02), count = c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: cool method, did not know it!

Comment: unfortunately this is not what I'm looking for, I've added more details to the original question above.

Comment: perhaps explain in words, not code, how `count` is defined?

Comment: For each row, count is the number of 'value's in the dataset that meet the min max criteria (for the row).

Comment: okay, but that definition doesn't provide any reason why rows 2 and 3, which both have a count equal to 2, should have the same ID.. That is, what makes count values "hang together"?  Rows 5,6,7,8 all have count=2 in your example, yet for some reason 5 and 6 get the same id (4) while  rows 7 and 8 get a separate (but again equal) id (5).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer because your goals are currently unclear, but I think this will provide you some tools with which to get there.

You have your data (note that the data provided is different from the tables in the question)

```
dat <- setDT(structure(list(value = c(94.01, 94.02, 94.03, 95, 100, 100.1, 200, 200.1), min_val = c(94, 94, 94.01, 94.98, 99, 99.1, 199, 199), max_val = c(94.02, 94.03, 94.04, 95.02, 101, 101, 201, 201)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L)))
```

You have a column of numeric values, and two columns representing the lower and upper boundaries of a range. A count can be done per row either with respect to the value or the range. If the count is per value, then it tells us how many different rows have a range that the value on this row fits into. If the count is per range, then it will tell us how many different rows total have a value that fits into this range.

The easiest way to think about it is to merge your example according to the rules while providing yourself with all of the merged columns to look at and think about. If we do a self-merge with data.table, we have x (on the outside) and i (on the inside). We can label the columns respectively.

```
dat[dat,
 on = .(value > min_val, value < max_val),
 .(x.value, x.min_val, x.max_val, i.value, i.min_val, i.max_val)]
```

We can temporarily save this into another variable while we're figuring out what we want.

```
merged <- dat[dat,
 on = .(value > min_val, value < max_val),
 .(x.value, x.min_val, x.max_val, i.value, i.min_val, i.max_val)]
```

Then we can, for example, either get the count within the row's range, or the ranges that the value falls into by deciding what columns we want to group together. If we group together the i columns, they were the min_val and max_val comparison, so we can count the number of values within the range. If we group together the x columns, we look at the value in the row for our count.

```
merged[,
       .(`Count Within This Range` = .N),
       .(i.value, i.min_val, i.max_val)]
merged[,
       .(`Ranges Value Falls Into` = .N),
       .(x.value, x.min_val, x.max_val)]
```

If I'm reading between the lines, I think you want a group ID that tells you which items end up falling within the same range sequentially, but you're going to have to be more explicit about what precisely should generate the id column. Hopefully being able to look at it like this will help out!